# Pdf to Png with Python in Lambda- error :"Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"

Tags: aws-lambda, python-packaging

By using Python 3.8 in Lambda, I'm trying to convert pdf files to png on the trigger.

Earlier I was having an issue with pdf2image dependency and that got resolved and now I have an issue with poppler. Please do help me to resolve this issue.

{
"errorMessage": "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?",
"errorType": "PDFInfoNotInstalledError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 75, in pdf_to_image\n    images = convert_from_bytes(infile,\n",
"  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 270, in convert_from_bytes\n    return convert_from_path(\n",
"  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 97, in convert_from_path\n    page_count = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)["Pages"]\n",
"  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 467, in pdfinfo_from_path\n    raise PDFInfoNotInstalledError(\n"
]
}

Thanks in advance!